# Best Practises - BackBone JS - Model View Relationship

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model

I need some suggestions around what should be the best-practice for the below scenario :

```
1. *Who (Model or View ) should hold the promise when a "FETCH" is called upon the Model ?*
```

For example :

```
Model FOO --> initialize: { .....this.promise = this.fetch(); }

View view --> someWhere: { var foo=new Foo(); foo.promise.done(..do something here)  }

OR 

 Model FOO --> initialize: { ... }
 View view --> someWhere: { var foo=new Foo(); 
 var myPromise=foo.fetch();myPromise.done(..do something..)  }
```

....

```
 2. Second Question is around whether Initializing a Model 
  should automatically call the fetch ? ( As noted in the above Example )
```

*There is no harm in doing either ways but I am not able to figure pros-cons of over each either style. Your opinion is appreciated*

Answer (score 1):

All anwers are in the [official docs](http://backbonejs.org/).

1) You don't need to hold that promise unless you going to use it later in other methods (which looks strange).
[`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) method returns a [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) which is exactly a promise (Deferred). You can use it immediately in the place where you call `fetch` without holding a promise instance.

E.g.:

```
model.fetch().done(..do something here..);
```

2) Quote from the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-bootstrap):

> When your app first loads, it's common to have a set of initial models
>   that you know you're going to need, in order to render the page.
>   Instead of firing an extra AJAX request to `fetch` them, a nicer pattern
>   is to have their data already bootstrapped into the page. You can then
>   use `reset` to populate your collections with the initial data.